# How to query the Twitter 1.1 API using your granted oauth_token?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

The Twitter 1.1 API requires an [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) token. My understanding of OAuth is that you need to request an authentication token using a cunsumer key, sectret, nounce, etc. Once you have received an OAuth token you should be able to access the API using ONLY that OAuth token.

When following the steps on Twitter I get examples on how to authenticate/sign the token, but I can't seem to find an example on how to access the (e.g. search) API with my oauth_token.

When executing the following GET request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=freebandname
```

I get (of course) a 'Bad Authentication data' response.

I would expect it would work when adding the granted OAuth token, but I have no idea how to do that.

Executing:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=freebandname&oauth_token=aaaxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

Also it returns a 'Bad Authentication data' response.

I also tried to pass only the oauth_token in the header, but this also returns a 'Bad Authentication data' response.

So basically my question is:

How do I request the Twitter 1.1 API with only your granted OAuth token?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I finally found the answer and it was pretty clear in the Twitter API 1.1 documentation. The documentation says you have to pass the token in the request header with the name 'Bearer'.

Everything is pretty clear explained here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

For the implementation, scroll down to the 'Issuing application-only requests' section.

Comment: can you please give the example of URL which has solve this problem

Comment: Documentation on this page https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth says:

`To use the bearer token, construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization header with the value of Bearer <base64 bearer token value from step 2>.`

But if header is constructed as described there ("Authorization: Bearer base64_encoded_bearer") then it fails with 401: Unauthorized http error.

And I found it works with raw bearer value not encoded with Base64.